# UNIX: Using awk commands to filter lists?

Tags: unix, permissions, awk

I'm wondering what is the syntax error in my command I'm using.

In the current directory I use the command `ls -l` to retrieve file permissions in my directory.

How would I do a query to see which files are readable, writeable, and executable by the user and then print a filtered list using awk?

I know the bits I'm interested in are the second, third, and fourth.

For example,

```
-rw-r----- .. .. .. ..
```

or

```
drw-r----- .. .. .. ..
```

I have an awk command as follows:

```
ls -l | awk '{if{$1 == /.rwx....../}print "line"}'
```

I've tried many things but there's still a syntax error.

Any help is greatly appreciated! Thanks in advance!

Comment: If your system has `stat` you should use that instead of [parsing `ls`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs).  Also, if your `find` supports it, try `find -perms u=rw -type f` or other permissions such as `u=rwx`, `-g=x` or `/u=w,g=w`. See `man find` for information on the meaning of these patterns.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The operator used to check if a string matches a regular expression is `~`, not `==`. Also, use `()` around the condition in the `if` statement:

```
ls -l | awk '{ if ($1 ~ /.rwx....../) print "line" }'
```

Comment: Ah, noted, I made a typo in the question. Even as ~ it still gives me a syntax error. 

But the brackets. That was the problem. Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Dennis; it's best to avoid piping `ls` and if you're going to do something, you may as well do it properly using `stat`:

`stat -c '%A %N' * | awk '/^-rwx/ { print $2 }' | sed "s%^.\(.*\).$%\1%"`

or just in awk:

`stat -c '%A %N' * | awk '/^-rwx/ { print substr ($2, 2, length ($2) - 2) }'`

**EDIT:**

The above fails with files containing spaces (sorry). This considers spaces and newline chars:

`stat -c '%A %N' * | awk '/^-rwx/ {print substr($0, 13, length($0) - 13) }'`

Comment: The problem with using `$2` is that it fails for files with spaces in their names. This might be better: `stat -c '%A %N' * | awk '/^-rwx/ {print substr($0, 13, length($0) - 13) }'` (or you could use `%n` and `print substr($0, 12)` )

Comment: @DennisWilliamson Ahh yes my one liner fails to find files with spaces in them. Also, I think `%n` fails with files containing newline chars: `\n` gets expanded?